# CSS Grid: dynamically span the last column

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to automatically span the last column to occupy the remaining space in the grid? Basically I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.col {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col:last-child {
  background: yellow;
  /* missing magic here */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45402709/3597276

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, it seems that in current version of CSS grid there is no true magic like `grid-column: span auto / -1` as a universal solution. But for this particular case of 3x1 grid you can do something like the following:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.col {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col:last-child {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
.col:nth-child(1):last-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.col:nth-child(2):last-child {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```